Disable "Highlight references to symbol under Cursor" for Blazor (.razor files)
I was able to disable this feature in VS for C# but I cannot do the equivalent for Blazor in .razor pages.  Is it possible to disable this for .razor files?


This question is the same as the following question except mine is focused on .razor files and not C++.
C++

I didn’t find a setting to disable this feature in Razor, but you can achieve a similar effect by changing the background color: Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Highlighted Reference.
